# Async function working on PC but not on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, asynchronous, android-asynctask, async-await

I have this code in Unity3D (using .Net 4x).
in the async function i call to another function and this is never executed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class thread : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {       
        DoTaskAsync();
    }

    public async void DoTaskAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            doSomething();
        });
    }
}
```

The code runs perfectly in PC and do the job something.
But when i build for Android and run in Android, i got no errors, but job something is not done.

Any idea about this, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to await the `DoTaskAsync()` method where you call it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class thread : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {       
        await DoTaskAsync();
    }

    public async void DoTaskAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            doSomething();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the question is: why it runs on the PC? ¿?

Comment: Alex is right, this won't compile unless Start() itself is async void.And the code as originally written should work.